# MySQL Subquery check

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a question. 
This is my query:

```
SELECT 
  branches.naam as branche_naam, 
  subbranches.naam as subbranche_naam, 
  specialiteiten.naam as specialiteiten_naam
FROM bedrijfgegevens
INNER JOIN subbranches on subbranches.id = company.subbranche_id 
INNER JOIN branches on branches.id = subbranches.branche_id 
INNER JOIN bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten on bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.bedrijfgegevens_id = bedrijfgegevens.id 
INNER JOIN specialiteiten on specialiteiten.id = bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.specialiteiten_id 
WHERE bedrijfgegevens.id in 
  (SELECT 
    bedrijfgegevens.id FROM bedrijfgegevens 
  INNER JOIN subbranches on subbranches.id = bedrijfgegevens.subbranche_id     
  INNER JOIN branches on branches.id = subbranches.branche_id 
  INNER JOIN bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten on bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.bedrijfgegevens_id = bedrijfgegevens.id 
  INNER JOIN specialiteiten on specialiteiten.id = bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.specialiteiten_id 
  WHERE branches.naam = "test" 
  AND subbranches.naam = "demo" 
  AND specialiteiten.naam = "bla")
```

I think it's way to long and I am using the same tables.
What it does is: 
**subquery**: get the company id where "specialiteiten.naam" = "bla". 
**query**: get the other "specialiteiten" from that "bedrijf"

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a view.

If you want the values in a single delimited list, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT bedrijfgegevens.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', branches.naam, subbranches.naam, specialiteiten.naam))
FROM bedrijfgegevens INNER JOIN
     subbranches
     on subbranches.id = company.subbranche_id INNER JOIN
     branches
     on branches.id = subbranches.branche_id INNER JOIN
     bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten
     on bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.bedrijfgegevens_id = bedrijfgegevens.id INNER JOIN
     specialiteiten
     on specialiteiten.id = bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.specialiteiten_id 
GROUP BY bedrijfgegevens.id
HAVING SUM(branches.naam = 'test' AND subbranches.naam = 'demo' AND specialiteiten.naam = 'bla') > 0;
```